# Variation within a chromatography with the same sample

Tags: chromatography

What are some possible explanations to why the exact same sample in SEC HPLC differ in their peak heights, although it's the same chromatographic profile?

The sample contains cell culture medium (undiluted) into a 10mM phosphate NaCl buffer. Is it possible that the sample is overloaded, might this be the cause for such different results?

After each sample there's a 1x column bed volume (24ml) wash with the phosphate buffer.

Any theories based on experience or otherwise?

Edit:

**Sample 1:**

Peak 1: 166292μV,

Peak 2: 199835μV,

Peak 3: 168024μV,

Peak 4: 78483μV

**Sample 2:**

Peak 1: 96936μV,

Peak 2: 142119μV,

Peak 3: 148060μV,

Peak 4: 195584μV

**Sample 3:**

Peak 1: 56769μV,

Peak 2: 88114μV,

Peak 3: 82351μV,

Peak 4: 176517μV

Chromatogam looks something like this (Peak count from left to right)

[image]

Comment: Is this UV detection? Something else? Also, typically only integrals and never heights are compared, and integrals are only fully comparable when compared to a standard.

Comment: 280 nm. Alright, I've retained Area (μV*sec), % Area and Height (μV).. which ones do you suggest I use? I suppose area since that's the integral. Does is matter that the peaks doesn't have very good resolution? I.e the area of the peaks will probably overlap to some degree.

Comment: We need more details.  As Jan said, what are you actually detecting?  Ultraviolet or visual (UV) light absorbance?  Conductivity?  Light scattering?  Dye?  It's also not clear how the cell culture medium can be "undiluted" if you mixed it with 10 mM phosphate buffer.  What injection volume?  What column size?  What are the column parameters?  What if you inject blanks (just buffer) after the sample?  Do you see peaks?

Comment: Odd that peaks 1,2 and 3 go down in samples 1 to 3, but peak 4 is highest in sample 2.

Comment: Curt: I'm detecting with UV-light at 280nm as well as fluorescent light. The peak-values added are UV-light at 280nm. The cell culture medium is injected into the HPLC undiluted i.e it's the same concentration as one can grow on. Injection volume is 200μl. The column is Superdex Peptide
10/300 GL SEC. I use 0.2ml/min which is as low as the column allows me - tried higher flow rate but get less resolution. Buffer gives no signal (as it should).

Comment: MaxW: yes, it's a mystery to me too.

Comment: One theory of mine is that there's an overload. I'll check out the difference with diluted samples, will get back to you later. http://www.chromacademy.com/chromatography-HPLC-Column-Overload.html

Comment: Is this the same sample run 3 times or 3 different samples?

Comment: Also, if you're worried about overloading, you can test this hypothesis by simply diluting your samples.

Comment: Zhe: it's the exact same sample run 3 times. Yeah, I'm running 40 samples: 10x undiluted, 10x 50/50 WFL (water for lab), 10x 10/90 WFL and 10x 1/99 WFL. Will get the result next week to see if it's overloaded once and for all. One other theory is of course contamination which certainly could give different results..